# Dependency issue setting up eclipse feature-based RCP application

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I'm working through the "Todo" feature based RCP exercise ("From plug-in to Eclipse RCP") in the Vogella Eclipse RCP book (3rd edition) and I'm not able to launch the application.  As I understand it, the objective of the exercise is to start with a plug-in project and manually construct a simple feature-based RCP app using the plugin as the basis for the app.  I'm running the Mars release (4.5.1) on a Mac.  The error I get is:

> !SESSION Fri Dec 18 07:57:00 EST 2015
>   ------------------------------------------ !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2015-12-18 07:57:00.091 !MESSAGE
>   Exception launching the Eclipse Platform: !STACK
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>
> etc....

The problem is likely related to missing dependencies which I traced back to two related observations.

First, the todo.product editor doesn't contain a Dependencies tab as described in the book.  Instead, a Contents tab contains the list of features that constitute the product.  In that editor/tab when I click on the "Add Required" button, nothing happens. I am able to add the feature using the "Add" button. The 3rd edition of the book asks the user to use the "Add" button to add the feature and three other dependencies which are not features.  But the dialog for adding features only allows me to add the feature.  No other matching items exist and after adding the feature the matching items list is empty.

Secondly, the todo.product file contains no plugins although my feature.xml contains the plugin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feature
      id="com.example.e4.rcp.todo.feature"
      label="Feature"
      version="1.0.0.qualifier"
      provider-name="EXAMPLE">

   <description url="http://www.example.com/description">
      [Enter Feature Description here.]
   </description>

   <copyright url="http://www.example.com/copyright">
      [Enter Copyright Description here.]
   </copyright>

   <license url="http://www.example.com/license">
      [Enter License Description here.]
   </license>

   <plugin
         id="com.example.e4.rcp.todo"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

</feature>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I can try or investigate to get past this?

Edit---added contents of product file---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?pde version="3.5"?>

<product name="to-do" uid="product" id="com.example.e4.rcp.todo.product"                 application="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application" useFeatures="true"           includeLaunchers="true">

   <configIni use="default">
   </configIni>

   <launcherArgs>
      <vmArgsMac>-XstartOnFirstThread -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
      </vmArgsMac>
   </launcherArgs>

   <windowImages/>

   <launcher name="todo">
      <solaris/>
      <win useIco="false">
         <bmp/>
      </win>
   </launcher>

   <vm>
   </vm>

   <plugins>
   </plugins>

   <features>
      <feature id="com.example.e4.rcp.todo.feature"/>
   </features>

   <configurations>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime" autoStart="true" startLevel="0" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.common" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.ds" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.event" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins" autoStart="true"            startLevel="0" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator" autoStart="true"               startLevel="1" />
   </configurations>

   <preferencesInfo>
      <targetfile overwrite="false"/>
   </preferencesInfo>

   <cssInfo>
   </cssInfo>

</product>
```

**UPDATE**

Another observation: When I enable the run configuration to validate the plug-ins automatically prior to launching I get:
[image]

Then if I remove the JavaSE-1.7 entry in the plug-in execution environment, thus leaving the list of EEs empty, the number of missing dependencies reduces to:

[image]

But I haven't figured out how to resolve this dependency. The Contents tab in the product doesn't allow me to add it. I can add it to the plug-in and the todo.feature but that increases the number of missing dependencies.  I could try to keep adding to the dependency lists in the plugin and feature but that doesn't seem to be what the tutorial is suggesting. I feel like I'm missing something fundamental.

Comment: "Dependencies" is in the MANIFEST.MF/plugin.xml editor, not the .product editor.

Comment: I did see the "Dependencies" tab in the plugin but all the product screen shots I've seen in the book and online places a Dependencies tab in the product editor.  Also, the exercise asks the user to add org.eclipse.e4.rcp, org.eclipse.emf.ecore, and org.eclipse.emf.common.  If I try to add those in the plugin.xml editor, only the org.eclipse.emf.ecore succeeds. The others are not options.  Don't know what that reveals.  Installation issue?

Comment: Actually I think the 'Dependencies' tab in the .product editor was renamed to 'Contents' at some point to avoid confusion. The Add on the Contents tab should show you all the Eclipse features provided you have selected 'product configuration is based on features' on the Overview tab. Show us the contents of the .product file.

Comment: Thanks for the info greg-449.  I posted the contents of the product file.

Comment: @RichRamos It seems to me that you have to create a new feature project manually, modify feature.xml in it as the tutorial suggests and then annd the new feature project as a dependency in your original project. This link might be helpful: [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseFeatureProject/article.html#eclipsefeatureproject_create)

Answer (score 0):

I feel the fundamental step you missing out could be setting the 'Target Platform' .
Go to Windows-->Preference-->Target Platform(search)
refer
[Target Platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPrhU.png)

if no entries is available in the Target Platform window then click on Add--> Current Target:Copy Settings from the current target platform--> Location
this will be machine location where eclipse is present
refer
[Setting Eclipse location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnzF9.png)